# Calculating $ i \cdot (j-i) = r \mod n $ where$ j^2 = r \mod n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a problem where I have a number $ j $ with $ j^2 = r \mod n $. For some integer $ i $, I also have $ i \cdot (j-i) = r  \mod n $.

For example $ 69^2 = 3 \mod 61 $ and $ 18 \cdot (69-18) = 3 \mod 61 $.

Are there non-brute force ways of doing this?

Comment: Doing _what_? Do you want to find $i$ for given $j,r$, and $n$?

Comment: I'm trying to derive polynomial roots modulo a number that may possibly be composite.  My particular example equates to -i^2 + 69*i-3=0 modulo 61. The roots for this are 18 and 51 (mod 61) where 18+51 is 69.

Comment: Why, that's the Vieta's identities, they work just as usual. $i^2-j\cdot i+r\equiv0\pmod n$, hence the sum of roots is $j$.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll get reading.